# What are domain walls?

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, branes, domain-walls

Could someone example the basics of [domain walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_wall) (string theory) and what their properties are?

I've looked around but I can't find much.

Comment: If "domain wall" means a soliton with one spatial dimension tranverse to it then the D8-brane in type IIA string theory is the obvious candidate. D8-O8 systems are used e.g. in the construction of type I' string theory.

Comment: Related/worth checking: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726897/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674892